# How can I invoke Pointer Function in C++ from different dll

Tags: c++

I have two instances of .NET application (C++ & C#) plus third party app.
When the third party app call the initial method in first instance by passing PointerFunction then first instance send the pointer value to the second instance. I want to know is there any way to invoke same function from second instance?

First instance is a class library(C++) and second instance is Rest Api (C#).

[image]

Comment: It's not entirely clear which parts on your drawing are processes versus modules (exes or dlls). Generally, you can't use a pointer obtained in one process in another (since each process has its own isolated memory address space).

Comment: As I mentioned first instance is DLL Library which implement by C++, Third Party app load the dll and pass the Function pointer to the DLL, then DLL call the Api by sending in the function address (IntPtr). I wan't to invoke same function in Third Party App from Api.

Comment: As long as it's all in the same process, you should be able to invoke the function pointer from anywhere.

Comment: No there are two different processes. One the Third Party app + DLL and second one is Api

Comment: Then please refer to my previous comment.

Comment: I see, thanks for your answer. So is there any solution for this achieve? Even different architecture, like COM+?